# How do i append an auto increment primary key to another field in the same table?

Tags: mysql, yii, auto-increment

I'm using *yii active records for mysql*, and i have a table where there's a field that needs to be appended with the primary key of the same table. The primary key is an auto increment field, hence i can't access the primary key before saving.

```
$model->append_field = "xyz".$model->id; // nothing is appending
$model->save();
$model->append_field = "xyz".$model->id; //id is now available
```

How do i do this?
I know that i can update right after insertion, but is there a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your record is only assigned an `id` after the INSERT statement is executed. There is no way to determine what that `id` is prior to INSERT, so you *would* have to execute an UPDATE with the concatenated field value after your INSERT.

You could write a stored procedure or trigger in MySQL to do this for you, so your app executes a single SQL statement to accomplish this. However, you are just moving the logic into MySQL and in the end both an INSERT and UPDATE are occurring.

Answer (score 3):

Some more workarounds:

This is almost your approach ;)

```
$model->save();
$model->append_field = "xyz".$model->id; //id is now available
$model->save();
```

But you could move this functionality to a **behavior** with a custom afterSave() method, note that you'd have to take care about not looping the event.

Or just write a getter for it

```
function getFull_append_field(){
  return $this->append_field.$this->id;  
}
```

but then you can not use it in a SQL statement, unless you create the attribute there with CONCAT() or something similar.

Comment: +1 thanks, i was doing the `$model->save()` before, now i'm using afterSave() . Also all the examples i saw for concat() only use it in select not in insert, so i would be making two sql calls anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone else coming to this question might be interested in exactly how i implemented it, so here's the code :

```
//in the model class
 class SomeModel extends CActiveRecord{
  ...
  protected function afterSave(){
     parent::afterSave();
     if($this->getIsNewRecord()){
        $this->append_field=$this->append_field.$this->id;
        $this->updateByPk($this->id, array('append_field'=>$this->append_field));
     }
  }
 }
```

One way to avoid the looping the event(as mentioned by @schmunk) was to use `saveAttributes(...)` inside the `afterSave()` method, but saveAttributes(...) checks **isNewRecord**, and inserts a value only if it is  a new record, so that requires us to use `setNewRecord(false);` before calling saveAttributes(...).
I found that saveAttributes(...) actually calls `updateByPk(...)` so i directly used updateByPk(...) itself.